# Ruby Gem Twitter - certificate verify failed (Twitter::Error::ClientError)

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth, rubygems

I am trying to use the ruby gem 'twitter' but for unknown reasons I cant get it to work.

Here is the .rb code:

```
require 'twitter'

puts "Greetings, World!"
puts "Checkpoint 1"
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "xxxxxxx" #removed for posting
  config.consumer_secret = "xxxxxxx" #removed for posting
  config.oauth_token = "xxxxxxx" #removed for posting
  config.oauth_token_secret = "xxxxxxx" #removed for posting
end
Twitter.verify_credentials
puts "Checkpoint 2"
```

and I get the following error:

```
Greetings, World!
Checkpoint 1
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (Twitter::Error::ClientError)
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1126:in `get'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:73:in `perform_request'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:38:in `call'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:13:in `call'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-4.8.0/lib/twitter/request/multipart_with_file.rb:14:in `call'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:247:in `run_request'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:100:in `get'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-4.8.0/lib/twitter/client.rb:108:in `request'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-4.8.0/lib/twitter/client.rb:66:in `get'        
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-4.8.0/lib/twitter/api/utils.rb:82:in `object_from_response'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-4.8.0/lib/twitter/api/users.rb:50:in `verify_credentials'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-4.8.0/lib/twitter.rb:60:in `method_missing'
from C:/Ruby200-x64/AppCode/twitter_connect.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

I am a ruby newbie and I cant make sense of the client error... perhaps I am missing something. I have also confirmed my Oauth credentials are working in python.

Thanks in advance and I look forward to your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve my own question. For those having the same issue try using the following:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

It disables the SSL security but it allows you to process with troubleshooting. The underlying issue is an outdated SSL.

Comment: This does make the error go away, but you really shouldn't do this http://jamesgolick.com/2011/2/15/verify-none..html

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to ruby as well but are you using a Mac? It may be because of outdated SSL certificate files. Here's a link to instructions that solved the problem for me.
http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: I use windows 7. Didn't have any luck with with link and I have confirmed that my path variables are set. I also uninstalled ruby 2.0 and install ruby 1.93 and I encounter the same problem. I have tweetstream up and running. HELP!